# how to create template for adobe prelude using adobe extension builder

Tags: adobe, extension-builder3

I am new to adobe extension builder . I want to use adobe extension builder for adobe prelude . I have installed adobe prelude and configured adobe extension builder in spring tool suite as well and i have even created one .zxp file as well but i am not able to use that extension in adobe prelude . 
This is the link that i followed
 http://127.0.0.1:57868/help/index.jsp?nav=%2F3_0

And even for me extension option is not enabled in adobe prelude .[Click here to view the adobe prelude screen-shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7o0Yk.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ExtensionManifest Version="4.0" ExtensionBundleId="com.example.AdobeDemo" 
ExtensionBundleVersion="1.0.0"
    ExtensionBundleName="AdobeDemo" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<ExtensionList>
    <Extension Id="com.example.AdobeDemo.extension1" Version="1.0" />
</ExtensionList>
<ExecutionEnvironment>
    <HostList>
        <Host Name="PRLD" Version="[2.0,2.9]" />
    </HostList>
    <LocaleList>
        <Locale Code="All" />
    </LocaleList>
    <RequiredRuntimeList>
        <RequiredRuntime Name="CSXS" Version="4.0" />

    </RequiredRuntimeList>
</ExecutionEnvironment>
<DispatchInfoList>
    <Extension Id="com.example.AdobeDemo.extension1">
        <DispatchInfo >
            <Resources>
            <MainPath>./index.html</MainPath>
            <ScriptPath>./AdobeDemo.jsx</ScriptPath>
            </Resources>
            <Lifecycle>
                <AutoVisible>true</AutoVisible>
            </Lifecycle>
            <UI>
                <Type>Panel</Type>
                <Menu>AdobeDemo</Menu>
                <Geometry>
                    <Size>
                        <Height>200</Height>
                        <Width>200</Width>
                    </Size>
                </Geometry>
            </UI>
        </DispatchInfo>
    </Extension>
</DispatchInfoList>
</ExtensionManifest>
```

Comment: That link will only work on your machine, please share a valid link

Comment: Hi ,
Thanks for your response .
I followed the docs which is available in eclipse perspective (windows ->perspective -> open perspective  - > Adobe extension builder 3 - > create html 5 extension in 5 min)